# LibSVM turns all my training vectors into support vectors, why?

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to use **SVM** for News article classification.

I created a table that contains the features (unique words found in the documents) as rows.
I created weight vectors mapping with these features. i.e if the article has a word that is part of the feature vector table that location is marked as `1` or else `0`.

Ex:- Training sample generated...

> 1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1
>   10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1
>   17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 23:1
>   24:1 25:1 26:1 27:1 28:1 29:1 30:1

As this is the first document all the features are present.

I am using `1`, `0` as class labels.

I am using **svm.Net** for classification.

I gave `300` weight vectors manually classified as training data and the model generated is taking all the vectors as support vectors, which is surely overfitting.

My **total features** (`unique words/row count` in feature vector DB table) is `7610`.

What could be the reason?

Because of this over fitting my project is now in pretty bad shape. It is classifying every article available as a positive article.

In **LibSVM** binary classification is there any restriction on the class label?

I am using `0`, `1` instead of `-1` and `+1`. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, a parameter search is probably a good idea before doing anything else.

I would also investigate the different kernels available to you. The fact that you input data is binary might be problematic for the RBF kernel (or might render it's usage sub-optimal, compared to another kernel). I have no idea which kernel could be better suited, though. Try a linear kernel, and look around for more suggestions/idea :)

For more information and perhaps better answers, look on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some type of parameter search, also if the classes are unbalanced the classifier might get artificially high accuracies without doing much. This [guide is good](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) at teaching basic, practical things, you should probably read it

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely try using -1 and +1 for your labels, that's the standard way to do it.

Also, how much data do you have? Since you're working in 7610-dimensional space, you could potentially have that many support vectors, where a different vector is "supporting" the hyperplane in each dimension.

With that many features, you might want to try some type of feature selection method like principle component analysis.

Comment: Found the reason, this is happening because SVM.net is not checking the validity of trainingdata. In my training data feature numbers were not sorted, as a result it was generating weird results. After sorting the weight vector on feature numbers and then generating the model things are far better...74% accuracy. Thank you.