# Maximum Support Vector

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, svm

I studying on SVM and Support Vector recently. for example if  I select Hard Linear SVM in a two dimensional classification problem with n Data, then result consist k=2 Support Vector. if I add another labeled data in previous data and retrain SVM. what's the maximum Number of SV?

I think N+1. but I need some proof. anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum bound on the number of support vectors, and the whole data set can be selected as support vectors. The proof is fairly simple (i.e.: left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: in the case of my example, the maximum number Is n+1?

Comment: As I stated, there is no maximum. The dimension of your problem does not matter. The number of data points does not matter. It is simple to prove.

Comment: can you make some hint? all of my problem related to the second part of question. with N data we have k=2 support vector, by adding one data and retrain SVM, all data  (N+1) maybe SV? it's strange !!.

Comment: I have already given you a huge hint, the problem is quite trivial. I won't go any further since this seems like homework. Yes, even just adding one datum can cause all points to become SVs.

Comment: and another question is, it's related to VC Dimension?

Comment: I've answered more than I should considering this appears to be homework. If you have a question where you can show your work, make that a separate question. Otherwise mark this one appropriately if you feel it answers the question with respect to the confides that SO is not a source to get homework answers.

Comment: it's not homework. I'm not student. I want to finding a relation between n data point and number of SV?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that N is the size of your training set, and giving the fact that all of them can be selected as support vectors then N is the maximum amount of SVs for that particular scenario.

You might also want to take a look on this: [What is the relation between the number of Support Vectors and training data and classifiers performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480605/what-is-the-relation-between-the-number-of-support-vectors-and-training-data-and)

Comment: can visualize any graphical example? when n data become SV? for example n=4 or n=7?

Comment: @user3677661 It is not accurate (specially the 4th exmaple) but I think you would get the idea... http://i.imgur.com/sHJpjuk.jpg